# Create new ArUco marker

Tags: opencv, aruco

Is it possible to train a new marker for ArUco? For example in ARToolKit there is a possibility to create new marker patterns and train them using mk_patt.exe, which generates pattern file that can be used to detect the pattern. Is it possible to do something similar in ArUco library?
I am interested in training following type of markers for ArUco:
[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could customize your own marker. Generally speaking, you just need to define the marker and tell how to identify the marker. Take a look at the source code of "marker" and "markerdetect" in aruco for more details.

Also the following link is very helpful.
http://iplimage.com/blog/create-markers-aruco/

Comment: the link given is broken